# Failing to receive broadcast udp packets in python

Tags: python, sockets, udp, broadcast

I'm trying to receive UDP Broadcast packets sent from FPGA connected via a LAN cable. the FPGA sends continuous packets to port 5001.

My python receiver code is simple:

```
from socket import *
s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.bind(('', 5001))
print "trying to receive"
msg = s.recvfrom(1024)[0]
print msg
print "I'm outta here! Bye!"
```

I checked using Wireshark, and I found that the PC receives the packets. However, my Python code doesn't. I also checked sending packets from another local python code (to the same address and port) and my receiver got those packets.

Wireshark captures:
 [image: Wireshark packets capture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the firewall permissions for python

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps others, I had the exact same issue, but in my case the [subnet prefix length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnet) was the problem, not the firewall.

The Ethernet interface on my PC was configured as `/16`, when for my device it needed to be `/24`.

Even with the wrong subnet prefix length Wireshark was still able to see the packets, but Python was not. Changing the Ethernet interface to `/24` fixed the issue. I changed it on Windows 10 by going to **Ethernet settings**, then selecting the interface my device is connected to, and under **IP settings**, clicking **Edit**, then updating the **Subnet prefix length**.